# Avoiding for-loops when aggregating timeseries

Tags: r, functional-programming, plyr

I get why vectorised functions are better than for-loops.

But there are some problems where I can't see the vectorised functional programming solution. One of those is summing monthly data to get quarterly data. Any suggestions to replace this code ...

```
month <- 1:100
A422072L <- c(rep(NA, 4), rnorm(96, 100, 5) ) + 2 * month
A422070J <- c(NA, NA, rnorm(96, 100, 5), NA, NA) + 2 * month
Au.approvals <- data.frame(month=month, A422072L=A422072L, A422070J=A422070J)

Au.approvals$trend.sum.A422072L.qtr <- NA
Au.approvals$sa.sum.A422070J.qtr <- NA
for(i in seq_len(nrow(Au.approvals)))
{
    if(i < 3) next
    if(all(!is.na(Au.approvals$A422072L[(i-2):i])))
        Au.approvals$trend.sum.A422072L.qtr[i] <- sum(Au.approvals$A422072L[(i-2):i])
    if(all(!is.na(Au.approvals$A422070J[(i-2):i])))
        Au.approvals$sa.sum.A422070J.qtr[i]    <- sum(Au.approvals$A422070J[(i-2):i])
}

print(Au.approvals)
```

Now with enough data to run as an example.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. You'll probably want to take a look at `ddply`, `aggregate`, `ave` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's create some bogus timeseries:

```
time_dat = data.frame(t = 1:100, value = runif(100))
```

To get a rolling sum, please take a look at `rollapply` from the zoo package:

```
require(zoo)
time_dat = transform(time_dat, 
                     roll_value = rollapply(value, 10, sum, fill = TRUE))
```

here I assume that the coarser resolution (quarterly) is 10 times coarser than the finer resolution.

---

Original answer for a non-rolling mean:

I like to use the functions from the `plyr` package, but `ave`, `aggregate`, and `data.table` are also good options. For large datasets, `data.table` is veeery fast. But to get back to some `plyr` magic:

First create an additional column which specifies the more coarse time frequency, i.e. which quarter is your observation in:

```
time_dat[["coarse_t"]] = rep(1:10, each = 10)
> head(time_dat)
  t     value coarse_t
1 1 0.9045097        1
2 2 0.4174182        1
3 3 0.5638139        1
4 4 0.8228698        1
5 5 0.7059027        1
6 6 0.5285386        1
```

Now we can aggregate `time_dat` for the coarser time frequency:

```
time_dat_coarse = ddply(time_dat, .(coarse_t), summarise, sum_value = sum(value))
> time_dat_coarse
   coarse_t sum_value
1         1  6.097348
2         2  4.834720
3         3  3.988809
4         4  4.170656
5         5  4.538269
6         6  6.198716
7         7  4.399282
8         8  5.507384
9         9  6.089072
10       10  4.663287
```

---

Comment: Thanks - but I really want the rolling quarterly sum on a monthly basis

Comment: @MarktheGraph Take a look at `rollapply`, see an extension of my answer.

Comment: Thanks found the following with your help:
Au.approvals <- transform(Au.approvals, trend = rollapply(A422072L, 3, sum, fill=NA, align="right"))
Au.approvals <- transform(Au.approvals, sa = rollapply(A422070J, 3, sum, fill=NA, align="right"))

Answer (score 1):

Paul's answer was great, but I just wanted to add that the chron package has many excellent operations for date/time classification which can be paired with plyr for aggregation

```
library("chron") 
# chron uses chron-specific object representation. 
# If a different representation is needed, a conversion is necessary
# eg. if a$date is a chron date object, I would us as.POSIXct(a$date) to get a POSIXct representation

# create chron date objects and values
a<-data.frame(date=as.chron(Sys.Date() + 1:1000), value = 1:100*runif(100,0,1))

# cuts dates into 15 intervals
a$interval1<-cut(a$date,15)
# cuts dates into 10 number of intervals using a label you define
a$interval2<-cut(a$date,10,paste("group",1:10))
# cuts dates into weeks
a$weeks<-cut(a$date,"weeks",start.on.monday=FALSE)
# cuts dates into months
a$months<-cut(a$date,"months")
# cuts dates into years
a$years<-cut(a$date,"years")
# classifies day based on day of week
a$day_of_week<-day.of.week(a$date)

# creating a chron time object
b<-data.frame(day_time=as.chron(Sys.time()+1:1000*100), value = 1:100*runif(100,0,1))
# cuts times into days - note: uses first time period as the start
b$day<-cut(b$day_time,"days")
# truncates time to 5 minute interval
b$min_5<-trunc(b$day_time, "00:05:00")
# truncates time to 1 hour intervals
b$hour1<-trunc(b$day_time, "01:00:00")
# truncates datetime to 1 hour and 2 second intervals
b$days_3<-trunc(b$day_time, "01:00:02")
```

I use chron a lot because it makes time aggregations much easier.

For additional awesomeness, the zoo and xts packages have many more functions which are great for various aggregations past the day level of detail. Their documentation is huge and it may hard to find what you want, but pretty much everything you want is there. Some highlights:

```
library("zoo")
library("xts")
?rollapply
?rollsum
?rollmean
?rollmedian
?rollmax
?yearmon
?yearqtr
?apply.daily
?apply.weekly
?apply.monthly
?apply.quarterly
?apply.yearly
?to.minutes
?to.minutes3
?to.minutes5
?to.minutes10
?to.minutes15
?to.minutes30
?to.hourly
?to.daily
?to.weekly
?to.monthly
?to.quarterly
?to.yearly
?to.period
```